# Want to know about grammatical term for substitutable part

Tags: pronouns, terminology, antecedents

I should think you call those nouns antecedent which are referred to by relative pronoun.

```
those nouns -> antecedent
which       -> relative pronoun
```

Then, what do you call those nouns if they can be substituted by demonstrative pronouns ?
Do they also called antecedent ?

```
  those nouns -> ?
  they        -> demonstrative pronoun
```

Comment: "They" is not a demonstrative, but a 3rd  person **personal** pronoun with "those nouns" as its antecedent.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when I made up the example including the pair...

Then, what do you call those_1 nouns if those_2 can be substituted by demonstrative pronouns ? Do they also called antecedent ?
<pre>
  those_2 -> demonstrative pronoun
</pre>

And, I understood that
those nouns referred to by so-called pronoun
are generally called antecedent.